# Any advantages of using methods to render vs variables?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Is there any real difference (advantage of using one over the other) between these two:

```
class Thing extends Component {
  renderStuff() {
    // Tons of conditional code, etc
    return someValue;
  }

  render() {
    return <div>
      {this.renderStuff.call(this)}
    </div>
  }
}
```

vs:

```
class Thing extends Component {
  render() {
    let someValue;

    // Tons of conditional code here, to determine the value of someValue

    return <div>
      {someValue}
    </div>
  }
}
```

Or does this just boil down to a stylistic decision?

Comment: If it's a constant anyway then there's probably no need to make `renderStuff` a method, although if that value never changes then why not just make it part of the HTML anyway?

Comment: Note the "programmatic things." Assume that's a big block of conditional stuff going on, too complex to just throw inside the main `<div>` block inside `render`.

Comment: Edited my post to be a bit clearer.

Comment: Logically I would make `render` contain code for *rendering* only and if `someValue` requires calculating with conditions etc have it inside the `renderStuff` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer:

The first way you solved the problem is cleaner and allows you to reuse the function `renderStuff`. Go with that one.

Longer:

Though it technically will involve at least one more function call compared to your second method, I doubt that will affect the performance of your code in a noticeable way. I would say it boils down to style, and I'd say that **your first version** is best. Your `render` function is cleaner & more readable, and you can reuse `renderStuff`. Your second option only has the performance benefit of one less function call.

Comment: To expand on this, react is all about compartmentalization, or modularizing your code. If you can break up complex queries and logic into smaller, more manageable chunks, then you're doing it right. If you have a `render` function that's 100 lines long to output a couple divs, you're doing it wrong.